# External access CouchDB in a windows server 2012 google-compute-engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have installed CouchDB in a windows server 2012 instance. It works fine and I can access the databases locally (localhost:5984/_utils). But when I try to access through the external IP, I've got 'This site can’t be reached... took too long to respond'... If I try only the IP address (without :5984) it returns IIS default page normally. I already tryied to put rules in firewall and even turn off firewall without success. [BTW: What is the difference of set External IP 'Ephemeral' or static (srv name)? (I also have tryied both)] Thanks !!! Evemar

Comment: In CouchDB configuration file, what is the value for `bind_address` for port 5984? If it's `127.0.0.1` change it to `0.0.0.0`, save and restart the CouchDB service.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably related to address binding. In CouchDB configuration file, what is the value for bind_address for `port 5984`? If it's `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` change it to `0.0.0.0`, save and restart the CouchDB service.

Also, try checking the firewall settings of your GCE network to make sure that a rule is configured to allow traffic for `TCP port 5984`.

Answer (score 0):

what type of authentication are you using in IIS? Depending on your firewall you may need to create a custom protocol (Different than a rule) then call that protocol in a rule to pass the traffic. I've had to do that before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I even tried to turn off the firewall without success...